# I want to reduce SQL SELECT SUM Duplicate aggregate

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate-functions

```
select sum(order_qty) as totalOrderQty, sum(stock_qty) as totalStockQty, sum(order_qty) - sum(stock_qty) as totalSubtract from inventory
```

Can we change the duplicate aggregate function into one?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse the sum aliases in the same select.  However, here is a slightly abbreviated version:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(order_qty) AS totalOrderQty,
    SUM(stock_qty) AS totalStockQty,
    SUM(order_qty - stock_qty) AS totalSubtract
FROM inventory;
```